# Load denied by X-Frame-Options: ccavenue iframe kit

Tags: php, magento, iframe, cross-domain, x-frame-options

I am getting following error

> Load denied by X-Frame-Options:
>   http://www.sarvins.com/checkout/onepage/failure/_secure%20/1/ does not
>   permit cross-origin framing.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Basically i am using iframe integration as:


`<iframe src="<?php echo $production_url?>" id="paymentFrame" width="482" height="450" frameborder="0" scrolling="No" ></iframe>
`
But when it is not showing because of the above error. Not sure it is occurring due to https because my domain is not on ssl

Comment: This is a web server configuration issue. Cross-Origin x-frame options have been set in the web server headers to stop exploitation. Check with your hosting provider or have a look at your master .htaccess file for modification so it will allow the particular website that you are pulling iframe content from. You can view the x-frame headers being sent using the Live HTTP Headers plugin for Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this issue also comes with me i have solve it
There are 3 type of submission custom data ,iframe and non-seemless 
if you want iframe integration yo have to do like this
when you make submit form in ccavenue like is

**Integration Kit**
            
                
                    Parameter Name:Parameter Value:
                
                
                     Compulsory information

```
                <input readonly="readonly" type="hidden" name="tid" id="tid" value=""/>



            <!-- <tr>
                <td>Order Id    :</td><td><input type="text" name="order_id" value="123654789"/></td>
            </tr> -->
            <tr>
                <td>Amount  :</td><td><input type="readonly" id="amount" name="amount" value="6000.00"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Currency    :</td><td><input type="readonly" name="currency" value="INR"/></td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_url" value="http://api.jeenees.com/ccavResponseHandler"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="cancel_url" value="http://api.jeenees.com/ccavResponseHandler"/>

                <input type="hidden" name="language" value="EN"/>

         <tr>
            <td>Billing Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="billing_name" value="Peter" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Billing Address:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="billing_address"
                value="Santacruz" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Billing City:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="billing_city" value="Mumbai" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Billing State:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="billing_state" value="MH" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Billing Zip:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="billing_zip" value="400054" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Billing Country:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="billing_country" value="India" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Billing Tel:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="billing_tel" value="9718165631" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Billing Email:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="billing_email"
                value="testing@domain.com" /></td>
```

if you want your ccavenue page in frame then you have two add this parameter in it

```
<td><select id="frame" name="integration_type">

 <option value="iframe_normal">iframe_normal</option>

</select></td>
```

then when you submit your from in ccavenue it automatically detect it is a iframe form